# Ubuntu 23.04 LTS wifi keeps disconnecting randomly

Tags: wireless, 23.04

HP Laptop 15s-eq2xxx

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 10:6f:d9:7c:54:57
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=6.2.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:73 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcf0ffff
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Your question appears to only be a paste of text?  Details in your *title* should also exist in the question, as not all browser/configs will show the title when this page is read (*not everyone uses large PC screens!*), and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the LTS, so your release details are unclear in the title too; LTS releases always being the first on the *even* year

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Jul 17 19:41:31 moharaja NetworkManager[684]: <info>  [1689601291.5567] device (wlo1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'manag>

Comment: @guiverc I have to restart the wifi every 2-3 minutes